# How to maintain session in android across different fragment/activity?

Tags: java, android, session-management

I have this code for session management during login using SharedPreferences. The code works perfectly during login but when i use it in another fragment/activity, it does not work anymore. I get the error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference".

Can somebody help me in correctly calling the sessionmanagement object? Here is my code

SessionManagement.java

```
public class SessionManagement {

//URL to our login.php file
public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://10.0.2.2:63343/login-test-session/login.php?";

//Keys for email and password as defined in our $_POST['key'] in login.php
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

//If server response is equal to this that means login is successful
public static final String LOGIN_SUCCESS = "success";

//Keys for Sharedpreferences
//This would be the name of our shared preferences
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "themoneygerapp";

//This would be used to store the email of current logged in user
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";

//We will use this to store the boolean in sharedpreference to track user is loggedin or not
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
```

ExpensesView.java(Fragment)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expenses_view, container, false);
    profiletest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtProfileExpenses);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SessionManagement.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = sharedPreferences.getString(SessionManagement.EMAIL_SHARED_PREF,"Not Available");
    profiletest.setText("Expenses for user: " + email);
    loadExpenses();
    return view;
}
```